# eclipse tomcat 7.0

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I'm trying to set up an Apache Tomcat 7.0 server in Eclipse, but I can't get the wizard to let me create it. My NEXT button won't highlight after I select Tomcat v7.0 like so:

[image]

I don't have the same problem trying to create any other version of Tomcat, just v7.0:

[image]

Info about my system:
-I've had it up and running previously, but had to go through a reboot with my system, Eclipse was untouched as it was on a different HDD
-I've reinstalled Tomcat 7.0 twice, once to the drive containing this particular Eclipse Workspace, and once to my main OS drive, both to no avail.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here or what's going on here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try window > server >runtime environments >add > tomcat 7 > next. and browse to the installation directory

Comment: ill submit this as an answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your eclipse menu go to
 window > server > runtime environments > hit add > select tomcat 7 > hit next 
press browse and navigate to the installation directory
and finish. Will solve this issue.

Comment: I have it already there : http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=2740653SERVER_.jpg - what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 13):

1. Close Eclipse
2. In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings delete the following two files:
   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
   org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
3. Restart Eclipse

Comment: i cannot see any other folders in workspace directory only project directories are present there. any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

1.Close Eclipse
2.In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings.      delete the following two files:
org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
3.Restart Eclipse